# VBA change cell color complete column bassed on example other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I got a workbook with 2 sheets.

- DATA which is the sheet I will import new data into
- COLUMN COLOR that will have the same column headers given a specific background color

Question:

I like to give the new data that will be loaded on the DATA sheet to have the same color for the columns like on the "COLUMN COLOR" sheet.

New data got various row numbers and number/text format

Color examples:

[image]

Data before color:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Worksheets("COLUMN COLOR").UsedRange.Rows(1).Copy
Worksheets("DATA").UsedRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```